# Dynamically expand canvas without stretching what is drawn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have a canvas where I add squares to the canvas. Right now, as you will see in the example I have included, clicking the button "expand canvas" does expand the canvas, but stretches the content that is already inside of it instead of fitting in the new content. How can I make it such that the new box will be shown, and the old box remains of the same appearance?

See at the following: http://jsfiddle.net/3q8tj17c/1/

Code is below:

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="canvas" width=100 height=100></canvas>
<button>expand canvas</button>
```

**CSS**

```
#canvas{
    border:2px dashed #00242D;
    border-right:none; 
}
```

**JS**

```
var canvas;
var ctx;
createBox()

function createBox(){
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
}

var squareCount = 0;
function drawSquare(squareNumber){
    squareNumber = (squareNumber*100) + 35
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth="6";
    ctx.setLineDash([0]);
    ctx.fillStyle="#006C85";
    ctx.strokeStyle="#008BAB";
    ctx.fillRect(squareNumber,35,30,30);
    ctx.rect(squareNumber,35,30,30); 
    ctx.stroke();
    squareCount++;
}

function drawborderRight(squareNumber){
    squareNumber = (squareNumber * 100) - 1
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.setLineDash([8]);
    ctx.lineWidth="1";
    ctx.strokeStyle="#00242D";
    ctx.moveTo(squareNumber,0);
    ctx.lineTo(squareNumber, 100);
    ctx.stroke();    
}

function addBoxText(text, squareNumber){
    squareNumber = (squareNumber*100) + 50;
    ctx.textAlign="center";
    ctx.font = "16px Segoe UI Light";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#333"
    ctx.fillText(text,squareNumber,90)   
}

$('button').on('click', function() {
    canvasSize = (squareCount*100) + 100
    addBoxText("hello",squareCount)
    drawSquare(squareCount)
    drawborderRight(squareCount)
    $('#canvas').width(canvasSize).height(100);
})

addBoxText("blah",squareCount)
drawSquare(squareCount)
drawborderRight(squareCount)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is wrong.

```
$("#canvas").width(canvasWidth)
```

That's jQuery setting the CSS width, you need to set the canvas's width attribute. Note that this will erase the canvas (but you're redrawing anyway, so it's not a big deal in this case).

So you're onclick function should look something like this

```
$('button').on('click', function() {

  squareCount++;
  canvasSize = (squareCount*100);
  $('#canvas')[0].width = canvasSize;
  for (var i=0; i<squareCount; i++){
    addBoxText("hello",i)
    drawSquare(i)
  }

  drawborderRight(squareCount);
})
```

EDIT: Changed around the order of things to produce the desired behavior. The key change is redrawing ALL the square after you resize the canvas, since, as I noted earlier changing the canvas dimensions clears the canvas.

Comment: Could also just use `canvas.width` since it's already defined and set. But this works too.

Comment: Adding the first element works ok, but the second etc. don't appear, perhaps because it is putting white space in before the created canvas? http://jsfiddle.net/3q8tj17c/10/ shows what I'm talking about...

Comment: Edited to produce your results

Comment: Since it is redrawing the canvas, it must erase the previous element, as shown by http://jsfiddle.net/3q8tj17c/12/

Comment: I actually need to save the content, but I can figure out a way to do that based on what @markE was saying, since http://jsfiddle.net/3q8tj17c/13/ shows that it will regenerate new strings...

Comment: You can do what @markE said, or you can just take a snapshot of the canvas before you redraw it either by using getImageData / putImageData, or by copying the whole canvas onto a buffer canvas. If you plan on adding hundred of squares that'll probably be more efficient than redrawing everything.

Comment: @hobberwickey.  Ouch!  Don't recommend snapshotting the canvas using `getImageData` or even `toDataURL`--it results in horribly inefficient performance!

Comment: Depends, if you're doing it in a loop sure, but if you're just doing once per click it's fine and a relatively simple way of doing it.

Comment: IMO & in my experience, Snapshotting impairs performance and should be avoided as contrary to best practice. Just saying it's a bad habit to get into. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`$('#canvas').width` changes the width of the canvas using CSS.

This will "stretch" the existing content to fit into the larger width so this is why your existing content is stretched.

If you want to use CSS to increase the canvas size, then you should resize both the canvas width and the canvas height by the same percentage to avoid distortion:

```
var pct=((squareCount*100) + 100)/canvas.width;
$('#canvas').width(canvas.width*pct).height(canvas.height*pct);
```

A side effect of resizing with CSS is that the content will become "pixelated" as it is drawn larger.

To avoid this pixelization:

- "Remember" which squares you've already draw (probably in a javascript object).

  ```
  var box1={x:35,y:35,w:30,h:30};
  ```
- Resize the canvas element rather than using CSS. Resizing the canvas element will also automatically clear all canvas content.

  ```
  canvas.width=(squareCount*100) + 100;
  ```
- Redraw all the previous squares using the information saved in their JS objects.

  ```
  // redraw box1
  ctx.fillRect(box1.x,box1.y,box1.w,box1.h);
  ```
- For efficiency, you will probably put all previous `var box` objects in an array and redraw all boxes in that array.

  ```
  var boxes=[];
  boxes.push(box1);
  for(var i=0;i<boxes.length;i++){
      var box=boxes[i];
      ctx.fillRect(box.x,box.y,box.w,box.h);
  }
  ```